# Customizing Google Charts to display text/number in charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Google API for generating graphs.

**My current Output is :**

[image]

**I want to display text/number in the bar as like below..** I could not find /missing the options to do it. Please let me know... Please do not say it not possible as it is 3rd party API. Its possible as they have done it for other Bar Charts... [Link Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)

[image]

**Here is my code.**

```
    //Bar Chart
      var data_bar = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Unit Tested','Passed', 'Failed', 'NA' ],
    ['BTEQ', 100, 20, 3, ]

  ]);

  var options_bar = {
    width: 400,
    height: 75,
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
    series: [{color: '#32B232',visibleInLegend: false}, {color: 'red',visibleInLegend: false}, {color: '#FFD732',visibleInLegend: false}]   
  };


    var chart_bar = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart_bar.draw(data_bar, options_bar);
    //end of bar chart..
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#SimpleExample, shows the annotation parameter and how to use it....

Comment: @SumitGupta : I tried with it.. its not working :( Please try yourself for my above code and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working answer...

```
  var data_bar = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Unit Tested','Passed',{ role: 'annotation' }, 'Failed',{ role: 'annotation' }, 'NA',{ role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['BTEQ', 100,'100', 20,'20', 3,'3' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've actually mentioned the link to the solution yourself:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Labels

Basically you need to add the following code similar to the `DataView()` mentioned in the link above, but now for every column of the data.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data_bar);

view.setColumns([0, 1,
                    {   calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation"  },
                    2,
                    {   calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 2,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation"  },
                    3,
                    {   calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 3,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation"  }
                ]);
```

Edit: to answer your question: the 0,1,2,3 refer to the columns of the data. In order for the annotation to appear the data from the columns (`sourceColumn: 1`), is transformed to a string with JSON function `stringify()` (`calc: "stringify"`). Note that with `setColumns()` you can use the data multiple times. `[0,1,1,1,2,3]` would mean that 100 is used three times in the DataView(). Here every column is used once to see the bar and the second time it is transformed to a string and used as annotation.

Your own solutions, although shorter code is more of a hack. Since you enter the data twice. This becomes a problem when you import the data from an external source.

Comment: what is meant by 0, 1, 2 , 3 in the setColumns ?